# Angular: How to access created DOM element in Child Component from Parent Component

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I need to do communication between `parent-child component`, which I implemented via `@Input` property and `onChanges()` method in the child component. **However, I need to access newly changed/created HTML Element which I unable to access.**

I am creating new ele. `<h1 id={{id}}> </h1>` on button event in `parent component`

I have implemented `onChanges()` lifecycle hook in `child component`.

However, it return `null` if I execute `document.getElementbyId(id)` in child component

*ParentComponent.ts*

```
export class ParentComponent {
  public ele: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  public changeElement() {
    this.ele = [5, 6, 7, 8];
  }
}
```

*ParentComponent.html*

```
<p>parent works!</p>
<div *ngFor="let i of ele">
    <h1 id={{i}}>{{i}}</h1> **<-- Here I am generating ele. with id.**
</div>
<app-child [ele]="ele"></app-child>
<button (click)="changeElement()">change Element</button>
```

This is the file which required enhancement in  `ngOnChanges()` method I guess. For simplicity, I made this example without semantic means.

**However, I am sure that I need to access HTML DOM element in  `ts file` itself for manipulation**

*ChildComponent.ts*

```
export class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() public ele: number[] = new Array();

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    for (let e of this.ele) {
      // this work perfect initially, because of ngAfterViewInit() hook
      console.log(document.getElementById(e.toString()));
    }
  }

  public ngOnChanges() {
    for (let e of this.ele) {
      // here I got latest values 
      // But I want to access generated ele, that gives null
      // How should I wait till view rendered onChanges()
      console.log(document.getElementById(e.toString()));
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: In general, you don't use the DOM. That's not how Angular is supposed to be used. What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am not understanding your finals intentions here, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I am drawing SVG line between two elements ( Like flow diagram), Now If I  add new element, I want to draw SVG line from last element to a new element. for that I need to access element into class file using `document.getElementById()` and pass to `drawLine(ele1,ele2)` function. But here ele2 is not generated in DOM but added into data. Did you understand ?

Comment: You can be notified when the view has been updated thanks to AfterViewInit/AfterViewChecked.

Comment: but if view change then how I can access newly created element

Comment: You could use the @ViewChildren decorator and subscribe to changes in the childcomponent. If something changes, just emit the changes through an EventEmitter via the ChildComponent to the Parent.

Comment: Have you tried using setters? I did something for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3s99bg

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, just add a condition on it like this:

```
 public ngOnChanges() {
if(this.ele){
    for (let e of this.ele) {
      // here I got latest values 
      // But I want to access generated ele, that gives null
      // How should I wait till view rendered onChanges()
      console.log(e.toString());
    }
}
  }
```

it worked for me

Comment: I wouldnt consider this a correct answer as Angular asks to not use the document cause it introduces serious security issues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i didn't pay attention to the document